# XCode - iOS: Can't resolve conflict between CocoaLibSpotify and Parse framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, spotify

I have an XCode project that uses the Parse API, but I'm now trying to integrate the cocoa touch wrapper for spotify. I'm getting an extremely frustrating linker error that I've literally been working at for two hours with no avail. Any help would be much appreciated! Here's the error. Thanks!

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Parse is linking to a Facebook SDK.
2. The project you are using is attempting to build x86_64 (the simulator).
3. The linker is trying to load symbols from Parse that use the Facebook SDK.

I'm making a guess here, but are you doing `-all_load` for CocoaLibSpotify?

See: [Using the Parse iOS SDK without including the Facebook SDK](https://parse.com/questions/using-the-parse-ios-sdk-without-including-the-facebook-sdk)

---

*after sending poor Zack on a fetch quest*

- Remove -ObjC and -all_load
- Add -force_load <CocoaLibSpotify library name> to load only CocoaLibSpotify.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the reply. Let me look into this really quick and get back to you in a few minutes.

Comment: What's the proper syntax for the -all load linker parameter? That may be my issue.

Comment: The answer was removing -ObjC and adding the -all load parameter.

Comment: @ZackMatthews Sorry I should have thrown that in. I'll do it now.

Comment: It looks like there are still some errors. For some reason whenever I make a call to SPSession I get a linker error. Here's the error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SPSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ListenInAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: CocoaLibSpotify doesn't support x86_64 or arm64 on iOS.

Comment: Is there a solution to get it working on those architectures?