# Getting compilation errors & warnings after install Soundcloud API through CocoaPods in Xcode

Tags: ios, soundcloud

Having problems with the Soundcloud API.

I'm getting multiple Warnings & issues and I don't know what can I do to fix that.

Have I to change header search paths & other link flags? I tried the Terminal version of Installation as well and I got warnings & compilation errors

Appreciate your helping, I'm stuck trying to run propertly the Soundcloud API without warnings and I'm not able to do that.

I attach some screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks a lot like a duplicate of [XCode - iOS: Can't resolve conflict between CocoaLibSpotify and Parse framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928940/xcode-ios-cant-resolve-conflict-between-cocoalibspotify-and-parse-framework/20929246#20929246).

I'm making a guess here, but are you doing `-all_load`?

- Remove `-ObjC` and `-all_load`
- Add `-force_load <SoundCloudAPI library path>` to load only libSoundCloudAPI.

After reading the [github page](https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI), you may not need `-force_load` at all.

---

You may also need to adjust your warning level because of all the deprecated APIs.

Comment: @santibernaldo In the project settings, "Deprecated Functions" aka GCC_WARN_ABOUT_DEPRECATED_FUNCTIONS must be set to NO.

Answer (score 0):

It's working!!! Thanks for your help!! I'm very happy :D I was forcing the loading of the libraries without the prefix libPods that is added installing the project through CocoaPods. The trick to hidden the Deprecated functions was really helpful. After one day trying different settings, its running.

These are the linker flags I put in "Other Linker Flags"

```
-force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libPods-OHAttributedLabel.a

-force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libPods-CocoaSoundCloudUI.a

-force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libPods-CocoaSoundCloudAPI.a

-force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libPods-NXOAuth2Client.a
```

In "Header Search Paths" I put "`./**`"

[image]