# Getting "Invalid Client" from com.spotify.auth with Spotify ios-sdk6

Tags: spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I am trying to follow the basic tutorial provided by Spotify [here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/tutorial/), but I am getting the following error when I try to authenticate:

```
2014-12-20 15:32:18.526 SpotifyTest[18319:53463120] *** Auth error: Error Domain=com.spotify.auth
Code=400 "Invalid client" UserInfo=0x7fcbb84c1e40 {NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid client}
```

What I have done:

1. My token exchange service is deployed to Heroku.  I used this [app](https://github.com/simontaen/SpotifyTokenSwap).  I have confirmed that the service is running.
2. I have triple checked that my Client Id, Client Secret, and callback URI are the same everywhere.(i.e. Spotify Developer Interface, Token Exchange Service, AppDelegate).
3. Linker Flags = "-all_load -ObjC"  (I added the all_load flag to fix [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928940/xcode-ios-cant-resolve-conflict-between-cocoalibspotify-and-parse-framework))
4. URL Types = my callback URI excluding "://callback"

Log from my Token Exchange Service:

```
2014-12-20T21:32:18.347945+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/swap" host=hidden-brushlands-8320.herokuapp.com request_id=903792bf-561d-4635-be85-5b1f27676afa fwd="<ipAddress>" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=407ms status=400 bytes=349
2014-12-20T21:32:18.347480+00:00 app[web.1]: <ipAddress> - - [20/Dec/2014 21:32:18] "POST /swap HTTP/1.1" 400 63 0.4018
2014-12-20T21:32:18.347821+00:00 app[web.1]: ip-10-87-143-248.ec2.internal - - [20/Dec/2014:21:32:17 UTC] "POST /swap HTTP/1.1" 400 63
2014-12-20T21:32:18.347865+00:00 app[web.1]: - -> /swap
```

I've never really done iOS development before, I just was interested in playing around with the Spotify sdk so let me know if there is any other relevant information I can provide.

Answer (score 3):

I was in the exact situation and could not figure out how to make it work. I finally realized that after changing the spotify_token_swap.rb file to the correct Client ID, secret, and callback URI, I had not yet committed my changes. The fix was to do the following:

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
git push heroku master
```

Also make sure you are testing on a device and not on the simulator (which will use the localhost URL for the swap service URL)

Comment: I checked that everything was committed and pushed to heroku.  I was running from a simulator, and my request is reaching the token service as the logs show.  The service is returning the 400 "Invalid Client" error.

Comment: @philosowaffle Like I said, try on your device, as the simulator will use the localhost URL